# Can defenders hold each other in the air at a free kick?

Tags: rules, football

I have noticed players standing in a line to block free kicks in the World Cup, with some teams choosing to have a player lay along the ground to block lower shots.

Are there any rules preventing teams from stacking players? For example: 3 players standing as the base holding 2 players elevated?

I realize it may not be the greatest strategy for defending, but is it allowed?

Comment: I wouldn't want to be a player standing on the shoulders of others, and to take a direct hit of the ball, off the boot of Marcus Rashford's left foot. One might end up in the back of the net.

Comment: It's funny, I was watching a Rugby match, back in Nigel Owen's days, when a player flopped and the ref (may have been Owen, may have been another) said something to the effect of "what do you think this is, football? Show some respect" ... I would kind of expect the same thing in reverse if a soccer team used a prop/jumper combo that way..

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe there is anything in the Laws of the Game (most likely [Law 12.3 "Disciplinary Action"](https://www.theifab.com/laws/latest/fouls-and-misconduct/#disciplinary-action)) which would *specifically* forbid this; Law 12.3 does include the catch-all allowing a player to be cautioned if they "show a lack of respect for the game" which a referee could use if they felt it necessary.

That said, the rules for sports in general don't need to include things forbidding behaviour which is likely to result to degrade a team/player's performance because there's no need for it unless people are being deliberately silly - in which case the "lack of respect for the game" clause does come into play.

Comment: I'm pretty sure such action would not be legal. I just need to find something in the LotG to quote for an own answer.